# How to hide the TabBar in TabPane?

Tags: javafx, tabs, fxml

I am trying to build a Next/Previous windows using `TabPane`. I decided to use `TabPane` as it is easy to use and design in **SceneBuilder**. At the start fo the app, I used this to hide the **TabBar** for now-

```
tabPane.setTabMinHeight(-10);
tabPane.setTabMaxHeight(-10);
```

The appearance of the TabPane after this-

[image]

As you can see, there still remains a small part of **TabBar** (below the titlebar). How can I hide it completely so that my `TabPane` will look like just a normal `Pane` but with all its functionality intact?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using a `TabPane` with hidden tabs as a wizard-type interface is an interesting idea, which I hadn't thought of and think I like.

You can hide the tabs with the following in an external CSS file:

```
.tab-pane {
    -fx-tab-max-height: 0 ;
} 
.tab-pane .tab-header-area {
    visibility: hidden ;
}
```

Here's a SSCCE. In this I gave the tab pane the CSS class `wizard`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TabPaneAsWizard extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        tabPane.getStyleClass().add("wizard");
        for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
            tabPane.getTabs().add(createTab(i));
        }
        Button previous = new Button("Previous");
        previous.setOnAction(e -> 
            tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()-1));
        previous.disableProperty().bind(tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().lessThanOrEqualTo(0));
        Button next = new Button("Next");
        next.setOnAction(e ->
            tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()+1));
        next.disableProperty().bind(
                tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().greaterThanOrEqualTo(
                        Bindings.size(tabPane.getTabs()).subtract(1)));

        HBox buttons = new HBox(20, previous, next);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(tabPane, null, null, buttons, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("tab-pane-as-wizard.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Tab createTab(int id) {
        Tab tab = new Tab();
        Label label = new Label("This is step "+id);
        tab.setContent(label);
        return tab ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

tab-pane-as-wizard.css:

```
.wizard {
    -fx-tab-max-height: 0 ;
} 
.wizard .tab-header-area {
    visibility: hidden ;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It solved my problem. Thanks a lot! Now I can design each page separately in GUI designer.

Comment: If you have multiple tabs opened, does this work for you ? In my case, for only one tab opened it works, but when I open another one the small bar appears as OP mentionned it in its example.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way of doing this is changing the colour to synchronize it with background

```
.tab-pane {
    -fx-tab-max-height: 0;

} 

.tab-pane .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: #843487;//your background colour code

}
.tab-pane .tab
{
    -fx-background-color: #843487;//your background colour code

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a little correction to your answers :

```
.tab-pane {
    -fx-tab-max-height: 0 ;
} 
.tab-pane .tab-header-area {
    visibility: hidden ;
    -fx-padding: -20 0 0 0;
}
```