# How to realize layouts in JavaFX like android fragments

Tags: java, javafx, panes

[That the toolbar and the navigation drawer were common to all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoOku.png)

P.S. Sorry for English!

Comment: I've never used Android and I don't know what Android panes are, but it looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556637/how-to-have-menus-in-java-desktop-application

Comment: Also (and I also have never used Android) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569204/is-it-possible-to-reload-the-same-fxml-controller-instance

Comment: thanks a lot dear @James_D 
I want something like this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQIscHJgBKY

Comment: is it possible to load another scene in AnchorPane???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using a BorderPane))

Comment: Can you share your solution with us please ?